# Spark JavaPairRDD iteration

Tags: apache-pig, apache-spark

How can iterate on JavaPairRDD. I have done a group by and got back a RDD as below JavaPairRDD (Tuple 7 set of Strings and List of Objects)

Now I have to iterate over this RDD and do some calculations like FOR EACH in Pig.
Basically I would like to iterate the key and the list of values and do some operations and then return back a JavaPairRDD?

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple7<String, String,String,String,String,String,String>, List<Records>> sizes =     
piTagRecordData.groupBy( new Function<Records, Tuple7<String, String,String,String,String,String,String>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2885738359644652208L;
        @Override
        public Tuple7<String, String,String,String,String,String,String> call(Records row) throws Exception {
            Tuple7<String, String,String,String,String,String,String> compositeKey = new Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, String>(row.getAsset_attribute_id(),row.getDate_time_value(),row.getOperation(),row.getPi_tag_count(),row.getAsset_id(),row.getAttr_name(),row.getCalculation_type());  
            return compositeKey;
        }
    });
```

After this I want to perform FOR EACH member of sizes (JavaPairRDD), operation -- something like

```
rejected_records = FOREACH sizes GENERATE FLATTEN(Java function on the List of Records based on the group key
```

I am using Spark 0.9.0

Comment: Can you show some of your work so far?

Comment: @Anas - updated my comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are talking about "FOR EACH", it really sounds like you want the `flatMap` operation, since you want to produce new values and flatten them. This is available for Java RDDs, including a `JavaPairRDD`.

Comment: could you tell how we can iterate over a JavaPairRDD<String,Double> someRDDName. I want to take the values of this rdd ,do some manipulations on the string and then save it to cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `void foreach(VoidFunction<T> f)` method. More info and methods: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#foreach(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)

Comment: But For Each does not return anything. What If I want to persist after the operation ?

Comment: This method is an [action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions). It´s prepared to interact to external storage systems. If you want to perform any operation first, you can do before save the data or do a [transformation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) first. You can use map or mapPartitions, for example.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to view some value of JavaPairRDD, I would do like this

```
for (Tuple2<String, String> test : pairRdd.take(10)) //or pairRdd.collect()
           {
               System.out.println(test._1);
               System.out.println(test._2);
          }
```

Note:Tuple2 (assuming you have strings inside the JavaPairRDD), change the datatype according to the data type stored in the JavaPairRDD.